# MongoDB - Unrecognized option: sharding.configDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect the config with the command:

**mongod --config etc/mongod.conf**

But it error:

**Unrecognized option: sharding.configDB**

My **mongod.conf:**

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
#storage:
#  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  journal:
#    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,93.115.21.61

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  keyFile: /home/ubuntu/mongo-security/keyfile.txt

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

sharding:
  configDB: "config/2.56.213.3:27017"

## Enterprise-Only Options:


#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

**MongoDB server version: 3.6.3**

Help please!

Comment: Why do you run an outdated version of MongoDB? It is EOL!

Comment: I assume you would need to start `mongos` rather than `mongod`

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-sharding.configDB): **mongos-only Options**